# Do I have a fighting chance trying to avoid $50 charge for miles credit with United MileagePlus?

Tags: loyalty-programs, united-airlines

I (actually a friend of mine, but I will use myself here for simplicity) have created for United MileagePlus account. I have flown twice in the past year with United and figured that it would help to get those miles saved up.

However the webpage on United website says that for tickets that are older than 31 day there is a $50 dollar charge to get those miles credited. 
Before I call United, do you think it is reasonable to pressure them into waiving those charges, since I want to become a new customer? Has anyone had some experience in this situation?

Comment: Unless you can demonstrate that you are going to be buying lots of expensive tickets in the future, but they might lose your business over this $50, I doubt it. But you can always try. The trick with the big 3 US international carriers and with Southwest is to exploit their size; if one agent doesn't give you the answer you want, try calling back later and hope you get one more amenable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you can show a high volume of travel (ie elite status on another airline) and are wanting to become a new loyal customer, United will likely not be amenable to waiving its rules.

Airlines like to lure customers to be faithful by offering the mileage programs, BUT they are stingy when it comes to awarding miles. Even if you have elite status, they are not quick to bend the rules when it comes to deadlines.

But as Choster mentioned, never hurts to try (a couple of times ;-)